# Insert array in a board

Tags: python

I'm trying to put an Array "a" into this board with this code, but i'm only getting a board with only the first number of the array, it seems that is missing and increment on variable "i" but i can't put increment without syntax errors near join, can somebody help ? thanks in advance. Here is the code:

```
`a = [25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

i = 0


def inc_i(i):
    i += 1
    return i

def board_draw(height, width, i):
    top = "┌" + "┬".join(["─"*6]*width) + "┐\n"
    bottom = "└" + "┴".join(["─"*6]*width) + "┘"
    middle = "├" + "┼".join(["─"*6]*width) + "┤\n"
    print(top +
          middle.join(
              "│" +
              "│".join('  {:02d}  '.format(a[i])
                       for y in range(width)) +
              "│\n"

              for x in range(height)) +

          bottom)

board_draw(5, 5, 0)`
```

[image: Im getting only this:]

I want each cell of the array with a different number...

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is because `i` is never incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i is not being incremented at any time. To keep your program "logic", try this:

```
a = [25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

def board_draw(height, width):
    top = "┌" + "┬".join(["─"*6]*width) + "┐\n"
    bottom = "└" + "┴".join(["─"*6]*width) + "┘"
    middle = "├" + "┼".join(["─"*6]*width) + "┤\n"
    print(top +
          middle.join(
              "│" +
              "│".join('  {:02d}  '.format(a[(x*width) + y]) for y in range(width)) +
              "│\n" for x in range(height)) +
              bottom
          )

board_draw(5, 5)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this returning what you want ?

```
a = [[25, 24, 23, 22, 21], [20, 19, 18, 17, 16], [15, 14, 13, 12, 11], [10, 9, 8, 7, 6], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]

i = 0

def inc_i(i):
    i += 1
    return i


def board_draw(height, width, i):
    top = "┌" + "┬".join(["─"*6]*width) + "┐\n"
    bottom = "└" + "┴".join(["─"*6]*width) + "┘"
    middle = "├" + "┼".join(["─"*6]*width) + "┤\n"
    print(top +
          middle.join(
              "│" +
              "│".join('  {:02d}  '.format(a[x][y])
                       for y in range(width)) +
              "│\n"

              for x in range(height)) +

          bottom)


board_draw(5, 5, 0)
```

[image: Output]

You may want to transform the list `a` like :

```
a = [25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

a_bis = [[n for n in a[i:i+4]] for i in range(5)]
a_bis
```

```
[[25, 24, 23, 22],
 [24, 23, 22, 21],
 [23, 22, 21, 20],
 [22, 21, 20, 19],
 [21, 20, 19, 18]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified and used the function `inc_i()` you have already defined to iterate the list and print the correct result:

```
a = [25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

i = -1
def inc_i():
    global i
    i += 1
    return i

def board_draw(height, width, i):
    top = "┌" + "┬".join(["─"*6]*width) + "┐\n"
    bottom = "└" + "┴".join(["─"*6]*width) + "┘"
    middle = "├" + "┼".join(["─"*6]*width) + "┤\n"
    print(top +
          middle.join(
              "│" +
              "│".join('  {:02d}  '.format(a[inc_i()]) for y in range(width)) +
              "│\n" for x in range(height)) +
          bottom)

board_draw(5, 5, 0)
```